# Data entered in a form doesn't insert into data table

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I cannot see the added data in the data table
this is the code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string t1 = textBox1.Text;
    SqlCeConnection conn =
       new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database1.sdf");
    conn.Open();
    SqlCeCommand cmdInsert = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmdInsert.CommandText = "INSERT TO table_name (Column1) VALUES (t1)";
    cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

It doesnt insert into data table
after clicking on the button, it gives me an error on 
cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: What's the error? Without knowing the error, it will be hard to diagnose the problem.

Comment: it debugs it, but when i click on the button, it shows me an error saying SqlCE Exception was unhanded. There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 8,Token in error = TO ]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because you query is not parameterized that's why you need to wrap it with single quotes,

```
cmdInsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table_name (Column1) VALUES ('" + t1 + "')";
```

the query above is prone to `SQL Injection`, here's how to parameterized it:

```
cmdInsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table_name (Column1) VALUES (@t1)";
cmdInsert.Parameter.AddWithValue("@t1", t1);
cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: @Kaf by `t1` was declared as `string`.

Comment: Unformatted question made my reading worse. I took mine away and + 1

Comment: This still didnt work out for me, i still get a error on cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: This is the error qlCE Exception was unhanded. There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 8,Token in error = TO ]

Comment: It is "INSERT INTO" not "INSERT TO".

Answer (score 0):

Recommend parameterizing `t1`. See [SqlCeCommand.Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcecommand.parameters%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
Parameterizing the values is a good practice to learn.

*sample from link*:

```
SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source = MyDatabase.sdf;");
conn.Open();

SqlCeCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();

// Create and prepare a SQL statement
//
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Region (RegionID, RegionDescription) VALUES (@id, @desc)";

SqlCeParameter param = null;

// NOTE:
// For optimal performance, make sure you always set the parameter
// type and the maximum size - this is especially important for non-fixed
// types such as NVARCHAR or NTEXT; In case of named parameters, 
// SqlCeParameter instances do not need to be added to the collection
// in the order specified in the query; If however you use ? as parameter
// specifiers, then you do need to add the parameters in the correct order
//
param = new SqlCeParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
command.Parameters.Add(param);

param = new SqlCeParameter("@desc", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
command.Parameters.Add(param);

command.Parameters["@desc"].Size = 100;
```